# With the last perk for enchanting can you add the second effect later?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Pretty much self explanatory... with the second effect perk in the enchanting tree do you have to add the enchant when you initially enchant an item or can you add a second effect later?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope. You can only enchant items that have no effects, so you cannot add a second effect to an item that already has one, even if you get that perk.